# Creating an upgrade package for dnn module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a module in production that I would like to upgrade with out losing any data. I can't find any documentation on how to write an upgrade package though. My change involves upgrading my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you originally developed the module.

If you by chance used my module templates, it is super easy.

1. Create a new SQL script (.sqldataprovider), this script should be only the CHANGES not recreating the same table. So if you added a column, the script should check if that column exists already, if not, add it to the table. If adding procedures, it should check if the proc exists, drop the original one and create it again (or you could use alter)
2. Include a reference to that and the version number for that in your .DNN manifest file.
3. Change your Version number in assemblyinfo.cs
4. Change your version number in the DNN file for the module's version.
5. Package the module in "release" mode again.

If not, you'll have to do all the above steps, but step #5 would be where you have to manually package the module into a ZIP file.

Comment: can you be a little more specific on the Manifest? In particular, should there be an uninstall for every version? Also, should my module implement IUpgradable? Is there any documentation on these upgrades, and any documentation on manifests?

Comment: One uninstall that runs for ALL versions, it should uninstall any database objects (tables, procs, views, etc). To do any of the above your module doesn't need IUpgradable, I honestly in my 11+ years have never once implemented a module that needed iupgradable for anything. Not much Documentation around DNN itself unfortunately.